# Visual Studio 2015 using a lambda in constexpr

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, constexpr

So in the latest Visual Studio 2015 the following code seems to no longer work:

```
template<class F>
struct wrapper
{
    constexpr wrapper()
    {}
};

template<typename T> 
constexpr typename std::remove_reference<T>::type *addr(T&& t) 
{ 
    return &t; 
}

template<class F>
constexpr wrapper<F> wrap(F*)
{
    return wrapper<F>();
}


const constexpr auto add_one = wrap(true ? nullptr : addr([](int x)
{
    return x + 1;
}));
```

Visual Studio reports back `illegal initialization of 'constexpr' entity with a non-constant expression`. This used to work in the release candidate, but the latest build seems to no longer work(I am using version `14.0.23107.0`). This should work(it does work in both clang and gcc).

Unfortunately, Microsoft doesn't let me report bugs. So does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: The problem is not exactly what you say it is. Change `true ? nullptr : addr(...)` to `true ? (void *) 0 : addr(...)` and it gets accepted, even if it uses a lambda. (I understand that that prevents `add_one` from having the type you want it to have, and I am not suggesting this as a replacement.)

Comment: If you want to report bugs, try http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio
(oh well, it says "You are not authorized to submit the feedback for this connection." to me)

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so it seems that visual studio has a problem with conversion of pointers with `constexpr` as @hvd has pointed out. A workaround, I found, I can do this instead:

```
template<class F>
struct wrapper
{
    constexpr wrapper()
    {}
};

struct wrapper_deduce
{
    constexpr wrapper_deduce()
    {}
    template<class T>
    constexpr operator wrapper<T>() const
    {
        return wrapper<T>();
    }
};


template<class F>
constexpr wrapper<F> wrap_direct(const F&)
{
    return wrapper<F>();
}


const constexpr auto add_one = true ? wrapper_deduce() : wrap_direct([](int x)
{
    return x + 1;
});
```

Comment: So, you want a `constexpr` variable with the type `wrapper<?>`, where `?` is the type of a lambda that adds 1 to its `int` argument, but with no way (within defined behavior) to either create or run a lambda of that type?

Comment: @Yakk This is the Paul that wrote [Static Lambdas: Initializing lambdas at compile time](http://pfultz2.com/blog/2014/09/02/static-lambda/), using `return reinterpret_cast<const F&>(*this)(std::forward<Ts>(xs)...);`. It is not guaranteed to work, that's for sure, but it does have a `static_assert` that would hopefully detect any problematic implementations. On many implementations, the behaviour would be defined: for types with trivial initialisation (which is admittedly not exactly what gets checked), it's valid to call instance members without actually constructing an instance of that type.

Comment: @hvd In what way is that better than a function called `add_one`?

Comment: @Yakk Lambdas allow specifying parameters as `auto`, functions don't yet. With the `int` though, I think I agree that there's no benefit.